# How to force pointer returned by new operator to be 32-byte aligned

Tags: c++, new-operator, avx2

I use AVX2 intrinsic in my program, and declare a __m256i variable in one of the class, like the following:

```
class A {
protected:
    __m256i buffer;
public:
    A() { 
        buffer = _mm256_setzero_si256();
    }
};
```

When I create an instance of A, if the memory location of buffer is not 32-byte aligned, I got a Seg Fault. Is there a way to force either the return address from new operator or the memory address of buffer to be 32-byte aligned?

Comment: Use [`std::align`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/align) and an allocator as in the example?

Comment: Alternatively your compiler may have a built-in aligned allocation functions, such as [`aligned_alloc`](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Aligned-Memory-Blocks.html) for GCC. - Then you'd need to placement `new` into the aligned storage

Comment: Thanks @UnholySheep. Temporarily I use aligned_alloc + placement new before I figure out why alignas does not work with G++. If you can post it as an answer I will mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you need placement new:

```cpp
#include <cstdlib>
#include <new>

using size_t = ::std::size_t;

template <size_t ALIGNMENT>
struct alignas(ALIGNMENT) AlignedNew {
  static_assert(ALIGNMENT > 0, "ALIGNMENT must be positive");
  static_assert((ALIGNMENT & (ALIGNMENT - 1)) == 0,
      "ALIGNMENT must be a power of 2");
  static_assert((ALIGNMENT % sizeof(void*)) == 0,
      "ALIGNMENT must be a multiple of sizeof(void *)");
  static void* operator new(size_t count) { return Allocate(count); }
  static void* operator new[](size_t count) { return Allocate(count); }
  static void operator delete(void* ptr) { free(ptr); }
  static void operator delete[](void* ptr) { free(ptr); }

 private:
  static void* Allocate(size_t count) {
    void* result = nullptr;
    const auto alloc_failed = posix_memalign(&result, ALIGNMENT, count);
    if (alloc_failed)  throw ::std::bad_alloc();
    return result;
  }
};
```

Now simply inherit from `AlignedNew<32>`.

See also this proposal, which has been accepted for C++17: [Dynamic memory allocation for over-aligned data](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0035r1.html).

Comment: I think the method of overloading new operator is more elegant as it doesn't require the caller to know any detail about the class. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Based on the comments, as the `alignas` specifier seems not to work:

Most compilers have a built-in aligned allocation function, such as GCC's [`aligned_alloc`](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Aligned-Memory-Blocks.html). This function can be combined with the placement `new` operator to create aligned object instances.

For example:

```
void* ptr = aligned_alloc(32, sizeof(A));
A* a = new(ptr) A;
```

Note: using placement `new` requires a manual call of the destructor, using `delete` does not work

Answer (score 0):

You could try an *alignment-specifier*

```
class A {
protected:
    __m256i alignas(32) buffer;
    ...
};
```

See §7.6.2 of the C++ standard.

Comment: Unfortunately neither "class alignas(32) A" nor "__m256i alignas(32) buffer" has any effect on g++ version 5.4.0 20160609, Ubuntu 16.04. I tried both and the result memory address still only align on 16 bytes.

Comment: @Harper did you use the `-std=c++11` command-line option when compiling?

Comment: I believe this does not work with dynamic(`new`ed) memory allocation: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0035r1.html

Comment: I need to use -std=gnu++11 instead of c++11

Comment: `<source>:35:13: warning: attribute ignored [-Wattributes]
__m256i alignas(32) buffer;
^~~~~~~
<source>:35:13: note: an attribute that appertains to a type-specifier is ignored`

Comment: @jbapple you are right. I didn't pay attention to this warning in the beginning. When I looked into the make log I noticed the same thing.